# Why I am getting error while Promoting Second Generation Package with dependent packages?

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, package-dependency, second-generation-packaging

> UPDATE: Facing the same issue even without package dependency.

I am trying to promote a **Pkg2** with a dependent package **Pkg1**. Both packages are 2nd generation manage package in the same namespace. I am able to create the Beta package with dependency but when running `sfdx force:package:promote` it shows following error:

> `The Subscriber Package Version Id or Package Version Id: 0HoXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX isn't defined in the sfdx-project.json. Add it to the packageDirectories section and add the alias to packageAliases with its 04t or 05i ID.`

Following is my `sfdx-project.json` file.

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "Pkg2",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
            "dependencies": [
                {
                    "package": "Pkg1",
                    "versionNumber": "0.2.0.LATEST"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "MyNameSpace",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "48.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "Pkg1": "0HoXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "Pkg2": "0HoXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "Pkg2@0.1.0-1": "04t7F000005EwwvQAC"
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I am also facing same issue today. Please let me know if you find any solution for it.

Comment: Could you please specify which package version is mentioned in the error? Pkg2 or Pkg1?

Comment: It is Pkg2 @blank

Comment: From id or seems like you're passing package id, where sfdx expects version id (-p parameter). Also, AFAIU you meant command `force:package:version:promote `

Comment: I already included -p flag with package alias `sfdx force:package:version:promote -p Pkg2`

Comment: You need to use `version` id, not `package` id or alias in -p parameter. Try `-p 04t7F000005EwwvQAC`

Comment: Thank you @blank for your support, you are right. I was using Package alias instead of package version alias.

Comment: I added an answer just to make it easier for other people to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though documentation says `-p` received package id, you need to use version id. So, in your case that would be `-p 04t7F000005EwwvQAC`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the package version id (04xxx), or the packageAlias from your sfdx-project.json under packageAliases.

In your example, should looks like:

```
sfdx force:package:version:promote -p Pkg2@0.1.0-1 -v devhubalias
```

or

```
sfdx force:package:version:promote -p 04t7F000005EwwvQAC -v devhubalias
```